# Digit of Life in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to create a method that will return a digit of life when receiving input of a date of birth in the following format: YYYYMMDD. The requirements are as follows (see image below):

I have tried the following:

```
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

date = input("Enter your date of birth in YYYYMMDD format: > ")
sum_list = []


def digitOfLife(date):
    sum = 0
    if(len(date) > 8):
        print("Input data too long")
        return
    else:
        date_list = []
        for char in date:
            date_list.append(int(char))
            
        while len(date_list) >= 1:
            print(len(date_list))
            for num in date_list:
                if sum > 9:
                    sum = 0
                sum+=num
                date_list.pop()
    return sum
    
print(digitOfLife(date))
```

However, I am not getting the result that is supposed to be produced with this algorithm. I know it has something to do with my logic which adds the digits of the list after it's been popped, but I'm not sure what it is.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me what result were you expecting and what was different when you ran it ? I tried it on my computer and for the YYYYMMDD = 20010320 it returned 9.

Comment: Hi Baymurat! I tried "19991229" and keep getting 2. It's supposed to be 6.

1 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 9 = 4 + 2 = 6

To add on, it only gives me an erroneous result when the first date adds up to a digit less than 10. In your example, that's why it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you would only need to perform modulo 10 on cumulative additions:

```
def dol(N): return N if N < 10 else dol(N//10+N%10)

date = "19991229"
dol(int(date)) # 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    while len(date_list) >= 1:
        print(len(date_list))
        # check if it's over 9
        if sum > 9:
            sum =0
        num = date_list.pop()
        sum += num
```

Check the above code maybe this would help you. And also check the documentation of pop() function from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)
Pop function removes the last element from the list and returns it. Like this :

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
x = L.pop()
print(x) # this will return 3
```

***This afterwards occured me that you can also add them straightforward and apply modulo by ten.

Answer (score 0):

A .pop() inside loop may cause a problem because size of the list is changing during the iterations.
Besides .pop() removes the last element.

I would suggest the following solution:

```
def digitOfLife(date):
    sum_ = 0
    if (len(date) > 8):
        print("Input data too long")
        return
    else:
        date_list = []
        for char in date:
            date_list.append(int(char))

        sum_ = sum(date_list) # calculate the sum of list of digits
        while len(str(sum_)) > 1: # repeat while the sum has more than 1 digit
            sum_ = sum(date_list)
            date_list = [int(x) for x in str(sum_)]

    return sum_
```

Also "sum" is a reserved word, so I renamed variable to sum_

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your piece of code:

- you should use a for loop istead of the while loop with pop .. this will make things easier.
- then when sum > 9, you should not reset the sum to 0, but add the digits together.

This gives you the following piece of code:

```
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

date = input("Enter your date of birth in YYYYMMDD format: > ")
sum_list = []

def digitOfLife(date):
    sum = 0
    if(len(date) > 8):
        print("Input data too long")
        return
    else:
        date_list = []
        for char in date:
            date_list.append(int(char))
            
        for num in date_list:
            sum+=num
            if sum > 9:
                sum = sum%10 +sum//10
    return sum
    
print(digitOfLife(date))
```

This will output what you expect:

```
Enter your date of birth in YYYYMMDD format: > 19991229
6
```

Other improvements are still possible, but this shows you the easier change to make in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Short way for digit of life:

```
def digitoflife(date):
    if len(date) > 8:
        print("date inputed is long")
    else:
        num = num2 = 0
        for digit in date:
            num += int(digit)
        for i in str(num):
                num2 += int(i)
        return num2
date = str(input('Enter the date: '))
print("The digit of life is: ",digitoflife(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
def bd_digit(string):
    total = 0
    for digit in string:
        total+=int(digit)
    
    if total >=10:
        return bd_digit(str(total))
    else:
        return total   
print(bd_digit('19991229'))
```

This may help you with recursion

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did the same exercise today like this.

```
date = '19991229'
list1=[]
for i in date:
    list1.append(int(i)) 

date2 = str(sum(list1))
list2 = []

for i in date2:
    list2.append(int(i))
    
total = sum(list2)
print(total)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def digitsoflife(number):
sum_ = [i for i in str(number)]
sum_ = sum(list(map(int, sum_)))
sum_total = 0
while len(str(sum_)) > 1:
    for i in str(sum_):
        sum_total += int(i)
        sum_ = sum_total
    print(sum_total)
    break
else:
    print(sum_)
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.